# Is it possible to override native fetch api to use a desired Promise library instead of native browser Promise?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-promise, onerror, fetch-api

Here is what I mean.

If the browser natively supports [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (for example, Chrome), then it uses the native browser `Promise`.

If I use another Promise library, (like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), for example), native `fetch` still isn't using it — it uses native `Promise` implementation instead.

Is there a way to override that?

Problem example:

```
window.Promise = function () { return null; };


fetch('/api')
.then(function (res) {
    console.log('fetch result!', res); // still works because it uses native Promise
});
```

Why would I need that, you may be wondering? I wish to make use [global rejection events](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html#global-rejection-events) which `bluebird` library supports and native Promises don't have.

Comment: The browser doesn't care if your using a promise library, it only knows about its own promises. It won't automatically change to a different implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some code that goes along the same line as @MinusFour suggested. Replace `global` with `window` if you're in a browser and not inside a module.

```
const fetch = global.fetch
global.fetch = function() {
    return Promise.resolve(fetch.apply(global, arguments))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use bluebird `Promise.resolve()` on the `fetch` promise. It will create a bluebird promise that assimilates `fetch` promise.

> Promise.resolve(Promise|any value) -> Promise
>
> > Create a promise that is resolved with the given value. If value is already a trusted Promise, it is returned as is. If value is not a thenable, a fulfilled Promise is returned with value as its fulfillment value. If value is a thenable (Promise-like object, like those returned by jQuery's $.ajax), returns a trusted Promise that assimilates the state of the thenable.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html

Comment: Excellent! I wrapped the `fetch` call in a function, and used this snippet: `return Promise.resolve(fetchPromise)`

Answer (score 0):

I found this too and thought it might make sense to post it here -
https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/417

The post says (in case the link in broken) - 
if you want to use bluebird in browser, use this, and

> window.fetch = null
>
> window.Promise = bluebird
>
> require('whatwg-fetch') the latest version browser may have fetch API
>   already, this repo will return false if there is fetch API.
>
> if you want to use bluebird in node, use node-fetch, and
>
> let fetch = require('node-fetch');
>
> fetch.Promise = bluebird